# character decoding failed. value corrupted

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, urlencode

This is my ajax call :

```
function callServer()
{
    alert('before : ' +uncompressed64Data.length);
    var compressed = LZString.compressToUTF16(uncompressed64Data);
    alert('after : ' +compressed.length);

    debugger;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : "/RegisterServlet_2/servlet/Register",
        type : "POST",
        data: "img="+compressed,
        cache : false,
        async : false,
        success : function()
        {

        },
        error : function()
        {
        }
    });

}
```

I am getting following error while try to receive it in error:

Character decoding failed. Parameter [img] with value [áº¢ã µå ¥ä?¢æ¡¥Æ´Û?à­ â¤¡á?®ã? ä??à©?má¹?â?¤â° â?]has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.

Fyi, 
1.I have mentioned header of html file utf8
2.server.xml mentioned

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

3.server side mentioned,

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

Please note I don't want any encoding and I just want to get the data which I sent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem caused by Content-Type, by default jquery use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. Try to set it up to `text/plain` or `multipart/form-data`. Here is [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Maybe problem that you compress it like UTF16, but server expects UTF8 as you specified in the headers.